# Conda: An HTTP Error occurred using try to retrieve this URL (install nbextension)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have set up anaconda3 on a work server (Windows) and asked the IT to whitelist:

```
*.anaconda.org, *.continuum.io, *.anaconda.com
```

I am able to launch the Anaconda Navigator and update the packages.

However, when I tried to install nbextensions for Jupyter on the command line:

```
Scripts\conda.exe install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

I am able to retrieve the dependency lists, but unable to actual download any packages.

I've posted the log below.

The funny thing is that I am able to enter the URL from the log message, for instance, https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-0.5.0-py36_0.tar.bz2, into the browser and it will start downloading.

So I am a bit puzzled what went wrong here.

I've also turned off `ssl_verify`.

Any insights?

**Log Message:**

> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>
> HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch/jupyter_contrib_core-0.3.3-py_2.tar.bz2
>
> Elapsed: -

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: i do not believe so.