# What URL should be whitelisted to use conda and pip?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am setting up an isolated PC to use for some tasks. In general, the PC should not have access to the Internet. However, I want to allow the users to install and use `conda` and `pip` to install some external libraries if needed.

In this case, what URLs I should allow the PC to access?

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+whitelist, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+whitelist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52010714/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51440710/7976758